# Resizing a textfield?

Tags: javascript, html, dreamweaver, textfield

I am trying to design/resize an input field to fit the design of my Photoshop theme. I am working in Dreamweaver.  My problem is, in Dreamweaver, the text box is resized, but when I go to preview or upload it to my host and view it live, it is just regular sized.  What am I doing wrong?

UPDATED: Not sure why, but my code is not displaying properly here... 
In my HTML I have

```
 <input type="text" id="test">
```

and I also tried  `<input type="text" id="test" value="" width="150" height="50" />`

I tried to work with a CSS style sheet as well and it is still resizing my box. Thanks for any advice you guys may have. I appreciate you taking your time to help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
<input type="text" id="test" value="" style="height:50px; width:150px;" />
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! I assume I can also add a style after the height and width to format the text that goes inside the box, correct?

Comment: @AoiHana: of course you can. I would like to suggest you to learn some CSS basics. http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_intro.asp

Comment: Thank you so much! I will head over to that site and read up.  Have a great day!